# Comparing a c++ std::vector's elements with each other

Tags: vector, iterator, standard-library, c++

I have a std::vector of double values. Now I need to know if two succeeding elements are within a certain distance in order to process them. <strike>I have sorted the vector previously with `std::sort`.</strike>
I have thought about a solution to determine these elements with `std::find_if` and a lambda expression (c++11), like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>::iterator> foundElements;
std::vector<double>::iterator foundElement;
while (foundElement != gradients.end())
{
    foundElement = std::find_if(gradients.begin(), gradients.end(),
                 [] (double grad)->bool{
        return ...
    });
    foundElements.push_back(foundElement);
}
```

But what should the predicate actually return? The plan is that I use the vector of iterators to later modify the vector.
Am I on the right track with this approach or is it too complicated/impossible? What are other, propably more practical solutions?

EDIT: I think I will go after the `std::adjacent_find` function, as proposed by one answerer.

Comment: "*I need to know if two succeeding ones*" => I believe you forgot to write a part of your. :)

Comment: Of course :) I guess now the post is more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about `std::adjacent_find`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enhance the grammar of your question?

"I have a std::vector with different double values. Now I need to know if two succeeding ones (I have sorted the vector previously with std::sort) are within a certain distance to process them)."

Do you imply that each element of a vector of type double is a unique value? If that's the case, can it be reasonably inferred that your goal to find the distance between each of these elements?

Comment: No, I don't implay that each element is unique, but it is very probably that that's the case. Anyway, it doesn't matter. The goal is not to find the distance, but to find the elements which are quite close.